# CORS error when trying to fetch from Github API + Spring Boot to Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, github-api

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getuser/{username}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("User-Agent", "profile-analyzer");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<User> user = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.github.com/users/"+ username +
            "?client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret,
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, User.class);
    return user.getBody();
}
```

What I'm trying to do here (Code above) is to fetch some data from Github API and it works fine and I can get the data to Angular (Running on Port 4200) as well.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getrepo/{username}")
public Object getRepository(@PathVariable String username) {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("User-Agent", "profile-analyzer");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<Object> repository = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.github.com/users/"+ username +
                    "/repos" + "?client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret,
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
    return repository;

}
```

But when I do this (code just above), in the same controller, my browser says something like this when I'm trying to access data from Angular server (Port 4200).

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/getrepo/dasunpubudumal. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’).`

What I have done is I have just changed the endpoint of Github which I'm trying to consume data from.

However, it gives the expected response when I access the endpoint of spring (Which is http://localhost:8080/getrepo/dasunpubudumal) directly.

How can I correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Comment: @JBNizet I tried adding 

`{
 "/getrepo/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}`

in proxy.config.json and changed the start scipt. Still not working.. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: If you're still sending requests to `http://localhost:8080/getrepo/dasunpubudumal`, then this is useless. The whole point is to send requests to `http://localhost:8080/getrepo/dasunpubudumal`, or simply `/getrepo/dasunpubudumal`. So that you don't need CORS anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working. Apparently the `getRepository()` function doesn't need a cross origin annotation.